# How can I replace component's state with react?

Tags: reactjs, state

I have a local state of `currentMenu` in component of `MenuItemContainer`

```
export default class MenuItemsContainer extends React.Component {
 constructor () {
  super();
  this.state = {
  currentMenu: [],
  };
}
```

I render `menu_items` by using function`_renderMenuItem` like below,

```
_renderMenuItems(menuitems) {
    const { order } = this.props;

    return menuitems.map((menuitem) => {
        if (menuitem.category_id == this.props.order.currentCategoryId) {
                this.state.currentMenu.push(menuitem)

        else {
            return false;
        }

        return <MenuItem
                key={menuitem.id}
                order={order}
                dispatch={this.props.dispatch}
                channel={this.props.order.channel}
                {...menuitem} />;
    });
}
```

What I want to do with `currentMenu` is that storing `menuItems` which `category_id` of `menuItem` equals to `currentCategoryId` of order state.

Now I am using `push(menuitem)` to push those items to the state. However, in `currentMenu`, it should store only if when category_id of `menuItem` is equal to `currentCategoryId` of orders state. So when there are changes of `currentCategoryId`, it should reset `currentMenu` and get new `menuItem`

How can I do this? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to actually trigger the state change you need to do this via setState
so you can add a setState command at the end of your _renderMenuItems method like so:

```
this.setState({currentMenu: state.currentMenu})
```

But the better practice is to have the state already containing the right items and not filter it in the render method.

Im not sure from your example how you are getting the menuItems, but in theory you should build the state from them and then call the _renderMenuItems method (that will use the state)

Comment: I am using `phoenix-framework`. When user joins to channel, it passes all `menu_item` to the state. Is it possible to query in reducer? for `currentMenu`. For example, I have all `menu_items` in order state, so if I can query by `category_id` in reducer,  it will be the best approach to get `currentMenu`

Comment: Im not familiar with phoenix framework. Do you use redux here? how does it set it on the state? in theory, if it sets it on the state you can use componentDidUpdate to filter your stuff